# Turning a HTML form input into an PDO variable

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I want the user to specifiy a number, this number will be used in my SQL statement when connecting to the database. If the user inputs five I want the five first rows in the table to be displayed.

If i write `"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID <= 5"` it works, but my variable is being fetched from a form. When I use `$variable = $_POST['variable']` and print it out using `"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID <= $variable"` no results are being returned. Why is that?

Comment: post your full code along with your form

Comment: Is $_POST['variable'] not empty? var_dump(it)

Comment: No, because when I echo it out it returns the correct value

Comment: Cant help without seeing the php and the form

Comment: Let's us full sql request

Comment: What is the actual SQL query being executed when you use the variable?

Answer (score 1):

you need to bind that variable if you use PDO.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID <= :id");

    // bind params
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $_POST['variable']);
    $stmt->execute();

    // fetch with
    // $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo "OK";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

According to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: `"if you use PDO"` ... `$conn = new mysqli` Somethings not quite right here..

Comment: i am sorry, i corrected it :)

Comment: `bind_param` that isn't PDO, it's `mysqli_` syntax. The PDO syntax is `bindParam`.

Comment: *According to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp* - `$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);` and not `$stmt->bind_param(':firstname', $firstname);` - If you're going to reference that link, then use the correct syntax for it.

Comment: plus, your answer is totally wrong. edit: ok, you fixed it.

Comment: feel free to post the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looked through the code once again, just a simple typo:

Works with:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM sql WHERE id <= ' . $items;
```

Before this I had

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM sql WHERE id <= $items';
```

Comment: The second code block would work fine with double quotes, however i recommend you edit your question to show the complete php code, then you should get an answer that will also show you how to avoid the glaring SQL injection vulnerability you currently have